# Pandas - Get week average for each user

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to take a dataframe representing players in a game, the dataframe has unique users and records of each day the particular user has been active.

I am trying to get the **average playtime** and **average moves** for **each week in the various users lifetime**.

*(Week is defined by a user's first record, i.e. if a user's first record is 3rd of January, their 1st week starts then and the 2nd week start the 10th of January)*.

**Example**

```
userid                          date          secondsPlayed   movesMade
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-04-28    413.88188       85
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-05-01    82.67343        15
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-05-05    236.73809       39
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-05-10    112.69112       29
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-05-11    211.42790       44
-----------------------------------CONT----------------------------------
++/8ij1h8378h123123koF3oer1    2016-05-05     200.73809       11
++/8ij1h8378h123123koF3oer1    2016-05-10     51.69112        14
++/8ij1h8378h123123koF3oer1    2016-05-14     65.42790        53
```

The end result for this would be the following table:

```
userid                          date        secondsPlayed_w movesMade_w
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-04-28    496.55531       100
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-05-05    236.73809       68    
-----------------------------------CONT----------------------------------
++/8ij1h8378h123123koF3oer1    2016-05-05     252.42921       25    
++/8ij1h8378h123123koF3oer1    2016-05-12     65.42790        53
```

**Failed attempt #1:**

So far I've tried doing a lot of different things, but the most useful dataframe I've managed to create was the following:

```
    df_grouped = df.groupby('userid').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').resample('1D').first().fillna(0))
    df_result = df_grouped.groupby(level=0)['secondsPlayed'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(min_periods=1, window=7).mean()).reset_index(name='secondsPlayed_week')
```

Which is a very slow and wasteful computation, but nonetheless can be used as a intermediate step.

```
userid                          date        secondsPlayed_w
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-04-28  4.138819e+02
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-04-29  2.069409e+02    
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-04-30  1.379606e+02    
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-05-01  1.241388e+02    
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-05-02  9.931106e+01    
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-05-03  8.275922e+01    
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-05-04  7.093647e+01    
++/acsbP2NFC2BvgG1BzySv5jko=    2016-05-05  4.563022e+01
```

**Failed attempt #2:**

```
df_result = (df
    .reset_index()
    .set_index("date")
    .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W'))).agg({"userid":"first", "secondsPlayed":"sum", "movesUsed":"sum"})
    .reset_index()
```

Which gave me the following dataframe, which has the fault of not being grouped by userids (the NaN problem is easily resolved).

```
date        userid                        secondsPlayed_w   movesMade_w
2016-04-10  +1kexX0Yk2Su639WaRKARcwjq5g=    2.581356e+03    320
2016-04-17  +1kexX0Yk2Su639WaRKARcwjq5g=    4.040738e+03    615
2016-04-24   NaN                             0.000000e+00   0
2016-05-01  ++RBPf9KdTK6pTN+lKZHDLCXg10=    1.644130e+05    17453
2016-05-08  ++DndI7do036eqYh9iW7vekAnx0=    3.775905e+05    31997
2016-05-15  ++NjKpr/vyxNCiYcmeFK9qSqD9o=    4.993430e+05    34706
2016-05-22  ++RBPf9KdTK6pTN+lKZHDLCXg10=    3.940408e+05    23779
```

**Immediate thought:**

Can this problem be solved by using a groupby that groups by two columns. But I'm not at all sure how to go about that with this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Try

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2015-04-24', periods = 50)).assign(value=1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2015-04-28', periods = 50)).assign(value=1)

df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['A','B'])

df3 = df3.rename_axis(['user','date']).reset_index()

df3.groupby('user').apply(lambda x: x.resample('7D', on='date').sum())
```

Output:

```
                 value
user date             
A    2015-04-24      7
     2015-05-01      7
     2015-05-08      7
     2015-05-15      7
     2015-05-22      7
     2015-05-29      7
     2015-06-05      7
     2015-06-12      1
B    2015-04-28      7
     2015-05-05      7
     2015-05-12      7
     2015-05-19      7
     2015-05-26      7
     2015-06-02      7
     2015-06-09      7
     2015-06-16      1
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Scott, this almost solves my problem! 

The only problem with this is that the grouper with freq='7D' seems to group not by the first date in the group but by the first sunday in the group's corresponding week.

Comment: I.e. the pre-group first entry has date: `2016-04-28` and the first entry post-grouping has the date: `2016-04-24`.

Comment: Okay, I am confused.  Do you want to group by Week for Sunday to Saturday or do you want to group by the next seven days?

Comment: I think you understood me completely correctly the first time, it is 7 days from the first date of each users entry. However that does not seem to be the resulting dataframe with my data. With freq="7D" I always end with groupings from Sunday till Saturday.

Comment: I believe what creates the problem is that the time grouper is shared across the many users, but created around one user. Meaning if user A's first entry is Sunday the 3rd Jan and user B's first entry is Monday the 4th Jan, and the grouper offsets is based on A's first entry, then both A and B will have a shared time group for their first week, being 3rd till 9th January. This is undesired because it gives A's first week up to 7 entries, while B's first week will be based on a max of 6 entries.

Comment: Currently these are the results that I'm having: [[original data](https://i.imgur.com/khHU81S.png)],  [[result](https://i.imgur.com/64agL2L.png)], [[longer result showing that other users share the same Sunday-Saturday grouping](https://i.imgur.com/9MjvHOg.png)]. 

I'm thinking maybe the right way about this might be to create weeknumbers like @Wen was doing and then group by userid and weeknumbers. Only problem with this has been that I would get weeknumbers for the first entries (0 and -1).

Comment: @ThomasHeiberg Okay, if I understand now, let's groupby then use resample with freq='7D'. Here you get two groups with each 7D sum starting on the first day of that group.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I wanted. And the solution is so concise and elegant! I've muffled my way around this problem and ended up with a slow and ugly solution - but this is much better!

Comment: Also if you find the time, is there any chance that you can enlighten me on whether or not there is a simple way to also add a rolling average for the weeks (possibly with a window of four weeks). No pressure on this question though, I do have a (very slow) solution running.

Comment: In any regard, thank you so much for setting time off to help me. I am impressed and happy that you are such a patient and generous being :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a newid help `groupby`

```
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['Newweeknumber']=df.groupby('userid').date.diff().dt.days.cumsum().fillna(0)//7# get the week number by the first date of each id
df.groupby(['userid','Newweeknumber']).agg({"userid":"first", "secondsPlayed":"sum", "movesMade":"sum"})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Wen!

I like the idea of the weeknumber help, however the results (as seen in the following dataframe: [link](https://i.imgur.com/uda6pzN.png) ), unfortunately does not seem to sum up across of the weeks. It only seems to add the weeknumber on top of the existing datevalues. Also meaning that weeks with no entries won't appear.